# How do I give Wujeeta a potion?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, I'm trying to do the Skooma Trade mission but it won't seem to let me give Wujeeta a healing potion so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong. Do I have to reverse pickpocket it into her inventory or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hm,you should be able to give her the potion simply through the dialog menu by accepting the quest and selecting "I have a potion for you".

You can see it for yourself here.

[More quest info(wiki)](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Skooma_Trade)

Comment: That explains it, all I have in my inventory are tradeskill potions. annoying that it won't let me do it anyway.